# How to make the docs/ environment use the local (yet unpublished) package version

Tags: dependencies, julia

A `ToyPackage` package at `v0.5.0` has a dependency on `Heavy`.

Then internals are changed such that the `Heavy` dependency is no longer required.

The `docs/` folder has a separate environment which has `ToyPackage` listed as a dependency at the latest published version (`v0.5.0`), and consequently has a dependency on `Heavy`.

How to remove `Heavy` dependency from the `docs/` environment in `v0.6.0`?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to make the `docs` environment depend on the local version of `ToyPackage` by

```
julia> import Pkg

julia> Pkg.develop(Pkg.PackageSpec(path="../."))
```

Comment: or just `] dev ../path/to/Package.jl`

Answer (score 0):

Use the Julia package manager for that. Just activate the project on `docs` folder.

Commands bellow assume that you are in `ToyPackage` folder:

```
julia> using Pkg 

julia> pkg"activate docs"
 Activating environment at `C:\YourFolder\ToyPackage\docs\Project.toml`

julia> pkg"st"
Status `C:\YourFolder\docs\Project.toml`
  [e30172f5] Documenter v0.25.2
  [29323fff] Heavy v0.5.0

julia> pkg"rm Heavy"
Updating `C:\YourFolder\ToyPackage\docs\Project.toml`
  [29323fff] - Heavy v0.5.0
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! The issue is that `Heavy` is not a direct dependency of `docs` environment, but an indirect dependency because `ToyPackage` depends on `Heavy` in `0.5.0`. When developing `0.6.0` of `ToyPackage` its `docs` environment should reflect the removal of indirect dependency.